# How to test the datepicker with selenium using webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, datepicker

I want to test the datepicker using selenium with webdriver in java when I click on the Start Date element.

This is what I have:

```
<input class="span2 start-date" type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" name="start"></input>
```

I want to select the Start Date with: (i.e. 2014-08-31)

Now when I try this:

```
System.out.println("Choose Start Date Icon");
driver.findElement(By.className("add-on")).click();       
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.day.active")).click();

System.out.println("Choose End Date");
driver.findElement(By.className("control-group")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.day.31")).click();
```

It's only working for the Start Date. For the End Date, it did not find any element.

Any help?
Please and thanks.

The code for datepicker:

```
<div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label">

        Start Date

    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append date datepicker-start" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
            <input class="span2 start-date" type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" name="start"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i class="enticon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label">

        End Date

    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append date datepicker-end" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="">
            <input class="span2 end-date" type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" name="end"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i class="enticon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What is your output? Please edit the question and include this.

Comment: the output is, unable to find the element

Comment: you said it finds the start date but not the end date? That means there is more to the output then "unable to find the element"

Comment: It will be impossible to help you without more code

Comment: Please attach full html code (with start date and end date elements). Thanks.

Comment: please see the code for datepicker, i edited the question. thank you